# Can't find images stored in folders

Tags: html

I've managed to build a website, which has tons of images. I stored all of those images in folder named "img". Inside the folder "img", there are some images and folders (which contains other folders containing images, too).

I tried to open it offline (with a browser), all the images show perfectly. But then, I uploaded it online, some of the images went missing...

[image: img folder]

So you see, the images inside folder "img" shows perfectly fine, but all images inside the folder of "img" went missing...

As you see, all the folder is online-friendly (right?). I can't figure it whats preventing the images from showing, as all of them shows up when i opened it offline ...

Sorry for the possibly confusing explanation...

EDIT : Server side folders

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R2qQ1.jpg)

EDIT : the code to call the images

```
<span id="kotakArt" class="col-lg-3">
                <a id="kotakBarang" href="product-bak-1.html">
                    <img src="img/BAK/Bak_Karet/bakkaret2.jpg">
                    <div id="labelArt">
                        <p><br>
                        Bak Karet
                        <br><br><br>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </span>
```

Comment: One thing I noticed is that all your sub folders are CAPS. Probably the problem is that. Maybe the file system in your server is case sensitive and what you have in local PC is not.

Comment: even though all the img's src link are written exactly the same as the folder name (with CAPS also) ?

Comment: Can you share your server image folder url?

Comment: Just did, it's exactly the same though ...

Comment: I can't figure out the problem just by looking at an image.

Comment: i'm sorry, im new to this whole thing, what do you need then ?

Comment: Can you share the actual url where your images are located

Comment: Your question is tagged `html` but you are not showing any HTML code.

Comment: @CharlieH here is the link [link](http://polaris-orionis.com/series-bak.html)

Comment: @Jocelyn I'm sorry, but i thought the tag HTML is the closest tag to this topic, i cant create new tags yet, i had to choose from the selection ...

Comment: Yes. Please copy a fragment of code where you try to show the images

Comment: @CharlieH i've added the code, thanks for keeping up with me, its very confusing to me ...

Comment: I did checks and it is surely `http://polaris-orionis.com/img/BAK/Bak_Karet/bakkaret2.jpg` not there. Not the problem of your code. It fails even when you put this url in the address bar. Please make sure the files are there.

Comment: @CharlieH yeah, i tried to deploy the website to netlify.com, which is a free hosting, everything shows up perfectly fine, so this is definitely a FTP issue, thanks for answering charlie !

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you moved the file to another folder or maybe  the FTP deleted thf images as soon as they were sent. Depends on the settings

Comment: i've tried to open the images through direct [link](http://polaris-orionis.com/img/BAK/Bak_Karet/bakkaret2.jpg) to the images, i can't find the image. But I can find the image in the FTP, i even re-download it and it shows up fine

Comment: Please use comments for discussions.

Comment: what OS are u using? Have you published the website